# I am trying to make my Figure elements (that work as links) be In-Line But Nothing I've Tried Works

Tags: html, css

So basically I have figure elements set up with clickable image links and a caption. Right now, I have the figure elements set to `text-align:center`, so they are all stacked up on top of each other in the center column. I have been trying to make it in-line, but everything I've tried, including `figure{display:inline-block;}` have not worked. Specifically, the `figure{inline-block;}` just resized everything and scattered the figures instead of making them sit in one line. I have no idea what CSS to use for this and need help.

Below is the HTML code for all the figures:

```
    <div class = "Contacts">
        <figure class = "Insta">
            <a href = "https://www.instagram.com/dulles.tsa/">
                <img src = "https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/instagram-logos-png-images-free-download-2.png"
                        width = "10%" height = "10%">
                <figcaption>Instagram</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class = "Gmail">
            <a href = "mailto:dulles.tsa@gmail.com">
                <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/New_Logo_Gmail.svg"
                        width = "10%" height = "10%">
                <figcaption>Gmail</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class = "Discord">
            <a href = "https://discord.gg/uYFVqsy">
                <img src = "https://discord.com/assets/41484d92c876f76b20c7f746221e8151.svg"
                        width = "10%" height = "10%">
                <figcaption>Discord</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class = "Twitter">
            <a href = "localhost:8000/contact">
                <img src = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c53e.png"
                        width = "10%" height = "10%">
                <figcaption>Twitter</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class = "Remind">
            <a href = "localhost:8000/contact">
                <img src = "https://www.pngkit.com/png/full/97-972295_remind-logo-blue.png"
                        width = "10%" height = "10%">
                <figcaption>Remind</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>

    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into `display: flex`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried display: flex, but all it did was warp my images.

Comment: You can look into this code and see if this is what you expect to see: https://codepen.io/maniczirconium/pen/NWNqXEO

Comment: @FrancisRubio Thanks so much, that works for me! You don't know how long I've been stuck on this. All I've got to do is make the pictures bigger and it'll be perfect.

Comment: Nice! Happy coding!